# Passing argument to a method called by symbol

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form-for

I am trying to call a custom method let's say 'get_divisions_by_school_id' and pass a variable to that method in simple_form_for

Instead of :divisions, I want to call :get_divisions_by_school_id(@school.id) in the following code:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:division_id, @teacher.standards, :divisions, :id, :id, :name,  {:class => "input-box-width1", :required => true},{:multiple=>true}) %>
```

I want something like :

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:division_id, @teacher.standards, :get_divisions_by_school_id(@school.id), :id, :id, :name,  {:class => "input-box-width1", :required => true},{:multiple=>true}) %>
```

Comment: `:get_divisions_by_school_id(@school.id)` is not valid syntax. If you want to call that method, call it without the colon(`:`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class method that takes a school ID and does it's thing:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base 
    def self.get_divisions_by_school_id(school_id)
        # Foobarbaz.
    end
end
```

And use it like:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:division_id, @teacher.standards, Teacher.get_divisions_by_school_id(@school.id), :id, :id, :name,  {:class => "input-box-width1", :required => true},{:multiple=>true}) %>
```